# Problems multiplying dataframe cells by matrix values

Tags: python, pandas, numpy, dataframe, reshape

Noob (trying to learn data_science) who has a simple portfolio in a dataframe. I want to sell a certain number of shares of each company, multiply the number of shares sold by the price, and add same to the existing cash value (15000), rounding to 2 decimal places. Briefly

```
new_port_df =
               Name   Price   Starting Number_of_shares
           0   MMM    10.00   50
           1   AXP    20.00   100
           2   AAPL   30.00   1000 
           3   Cash    1.00   15000

 shares_sold = [[ 5.] [ 15.] [75.] [   0.]] #(numpy.ndarray, shape (4,1))

 new_port_df['Price'] = 

           0    10.00
           1    20.00
           2    30.00
           3     1.00
           Name: Low, dtype: float64 # pandas.core.series.Series
```

so basically Cash += 5 * 10 + 15 * 20 + 75 * 30 + 0 * 1 or 15000 + 2600 = 17600

As an intermediate step (after googling and reading other posts on here), I've tried:

```
cash_proceeds = np.dot(shares_sold, new_port['Price'])

ValueError: shapes (4,1) and (4,) not aligned: 1 (dim 1) != 4 (dim 0). I think I should be reshaping, but haven't had any luck.
```

Desired result is below (all working except for the 17600 cell)

```
updated_port_df =
               Name   Price   Starting Number_of_shares
           0   MMM    10.00   45
           1   AXP    20.00   85
           2   AAPL   30.00   925 
           3   Cash    1.00   17600 # only the 17600 not working
```

Simply answers I can understand are preferred to complex ones I can't. Thanks for any help.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Rather than initiating shares_sold as a list of lists i.e. `[[],[],[]]` you can just create a list of numbers in order to resolve your np.dot() error.

```
shares_sold = [5,15,75,0]
cash_proceeds = np.dot(new_port_df['Price'], shares_sold)
```

or as Andy pointed out, if shares_sold is already initiated as a list of lists you can convert it to an array and then flatten it and proceed from there. My answer wont address the change of approach that entails.

You can then change the last item in your shares_sold list/array to reflect the change in cash from the sale of stock (notice saved as negative because these will be subtracted from your Number of Shares column):

```
shares_sold[3] = -cash_proceeds
```

Now you can subtract shares sold from the Number of Shares column to reflect the change (you indicate you want updated_port_df to house this information so I first duplicate the initial portfolio and then make the change),

```
updated_port_df = new_port_df.copy()
updated_port_df['Number_of_shares'] = updated_port_df['Number_of_shares'] - shares_sold
```

Answer (score 1):

You may use pandas `dot`, instead of `np.dot`. You need 1-d numpy array to using dot on series, so you need convert `shares_sold` to 1-d

```
shares_sold = np.array([[ 5.], [ 15.], [75.] ,[   0.]])
shares_sold_1d = shares_sold.flatten()

cash_proceeds = new_port_df['Price'].dot(shares_sold_1d)

In [226]: print(cash_proceeds)
2600.0
```

To get your desired output, simple using `.loc` assignment and subtraction

```
(new_port_df.loc[new_port_df.Name.eq('Cash'), 'Starting_Number_of_shares'] = 
              new_port_df.loc[new_port_df.Name.eq('Cash'), 'Starting_Number_of_shares'] 
              + cash_proceeds)

new_port_df['Starting_Number_of_shares'] = new_port_df['Starting_Number_of_shares'] - shares_sold_1d

Out[235]:
   Name  Price  Starting_Number_of_shares
0   MMM   10.0                       45.0
1   AXP   20.0                       85.0
2  AAPL   30.0                      925.0
3  Cash    1.0                    17600.0
```

---

**Note**: If you really want to use `np.dot`, you need swapping the order as follows

```
In [237]: np.dot(new_port_df['Price'], shares_sold)
Out[237]: array([2600.])
```